# How can I use Torch to make make 3, 3 shape tensor a 3, 1, 3 shaped tensor only in Torch?

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

If there is a Torch tensor of 3 x 3 how can I use Torch only to convert it to a 3 x 1 x 3 tensor?

Starting with this 3x3 tensor...

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
```

... That I want to convert to this 3x1x3 tensor

```
tensor([[[1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1.]]])
```

How can I do this in Torch?
I know it can by done by indexing like so...
`torch.ones(3, 3)[:, None, :]` but I need to do this in Torch and Torch alone.

I tried with this line...

`torch.ones(3, 3).unsqueeze(-1)`

But it gave me

```
tensor([[[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]]])
```

Which doesn't do the trick.

(The reason I can't do `torch.ones(3, 3)[:, None, :]` is that I'm using LibTorch in C++, and this type of indexing is not possible, but we can leave LibTorch and C++ out of it and just focus on if Torch can do this.)

Comment: `torch.ones(3, 3).unsqueeze(1)` or `torch.ones(3, 3).unsqueeze(-2)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `(3,3)` tensor `x = torch.ones((3,3))`. To reshape this to a `(3,1,3)` tensor, use `x.unsqueeze(1)`.